# Sum the values in each inputs

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I am trying to get the total value of each variable that's stored in the dictionary. I am a beginner who's struggling with this line of code. Can someone help me figure out the bug?

```
income_list = { 
    "Job": [],
    "Business": [],
    "Dividends": [],
    "Sideline": [],
    "Others": []

}
total_income = 0
job = income_list["Job"].append(float(input(f"Enter income for job: € ")))
business = income_list["Business"].append(float(input(f"Enter income for Business: € ")))
dividends = income_list["Dividends"].append(float(input(f"Enter income for Dividends: € ")))
sideline = income_list["Sideline"].append(float(input(f"Enter income for Sideline: € ")))
others = income_list["Others"].append(float(input(f"Enter other incomes: € ")))

for value in income_list.values():
 print(sum(value))
```

Comment: You should rather provide the dictionary(ies) that result from your input, right now your code is not reproducible as we have no clue what is the input.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: Update the question with what result you are getting.

Comment: is it more understandable now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension, given that you need a sum of sums:

```py
total = sum([sum(source) for source in income_list.values()])
```

This method will work even if your income sources contain multiple values (since they are lists).

The same result can be achieved by giving a generator to `sum`:

```py
total = sum(sum(source) for source in income_list.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this :

```
from itertools import chain

sum(chain(income_list.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want one of two things: 1) a list with dictionaries/objects, or 2) a dictionary with lists. I would go with 1) because it feels more intuitive to me, but since it seems you are already trying to achieve 2), I will do that as well.

I will provide a mimimalistic example, and then you should be able to extend it to your program.

```py
my_lists = {
  "list1": [],
  "list2": []
}

my_input = Input()
my_lists["list1"].append(my_input)

for x in my_lists["list1"]:
  print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it makes no sense to use a list as the dictionary value if what you want to store is a single value. Second, you need to add to the "total_income" variable in the for loop.

That code works:

```
income_list = { 
}

total_income = 0
income_list["Job"]=float(input(f"Enter income for job: € "))
income_list["Business"]=float(input(f"Enter income for Business: € "))
income_list["Dividends"]=float(input(f"Enter income for Dividends: € "))
income_list["Sideline"]=float(input(f"Enter income for Sideline: € "))
income_list["Others"]=float(input(f"Enter other incomes: € "))

for value in income_list.values():
    total_income += value

print(total_income)
```

That said, I think you don't even need to use a dictionary for that, just simple float variables.

Comment: hi! thank you! that code works but the thing is i need to use the dataframe after. sorry the code didnt support the operand with int and list

Comment: The dictionary is to make a dataframe for later btw